# set row names of dataset to be equal to another variable

Tags: r

data.frame example:

[image: dataframe]

Hi guys, I need to set row names of this dataset to be equal to the polling id station variable. Then I have to use row name indexing to report the name of the polling station with psid 089/081.

I'm new to r, all help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which variable is the polling station id ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual data as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very simple.

```
row.names(yourdf) <- yourdf$psid
```

Answer (score 2):

what about `rownames(df) <- as.character(df$psid)`?